# DjangoCMS: how to auto-add default plugins in placeholders

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a few placeholders in my DjangoCMS template (par example, header, contetent and footer). I want to **automatically populate** any newly-created pages with default items: header placeholder with header plugin and footer placeholder with footer plugin.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the [`CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf) setting, specifically, the `default_plugins` option:

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'footer': {
        'name': "Footer",
        'default_plugins':[
            {
                'plugin_type':'FooterPlugin',
                'values':{
                    'body':'<p>This is the footer</p>'
                },
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

This assumes that your `FooterPlugin` has a field `body` that allows HTML content.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a Default Plugin that has a value which is a `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 0):

One more hint: static placeholders are good for this purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to Adam Venturella question above (about plugins with foreign keys) since I just had to solve the same problem ... better late than never (maybe)

After digging through the source I found there is a hook you can add to your `CMSPlugin` after the default plugin is added called `notify_on_autoadd`. The signature of this is `notify_on_autoadd(self, request, conf)` where `conf` is the dict containing the `plugin_type`, `values`, etc ... so I added the additional foreign keys I wanted as a new key there (it won't work in the `values` key since this is passed verbatim as field values to make the `CMSPlugin`, but you can add it to the root ok) ... then in `notify_on_autoadd` I just make the new entries like normal from this `conf`.

Here is and example ot make it more clear:

```
class Story(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def notify_on_autoadd(self, request, conf):
        new_line_values = conf.get('new_line_values', [])
        for vals in new_line_values:
            line = Line(
                fmt=vals.get('fmt', '')
                text=vals.get('text', ''),
                story=self
            )
            line.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Line(models.Model):
    fmt = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    text = models.TextField()
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, related_name='story')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.heading
```

Then you would just add something like this snippet to your `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF`.

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    ...
        'default_plugins': [
            {
                'plugin_type':  'StoryPlugin',
                'values': {
                    'title': 'My Story',
                },
                'new_line_values': [
                    {
                        'fmt': 'normal',
                        'text': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
                    },
                    {
                        'fmt': 'bold',
                        'text': 'Everyone is sick of Lorem Ipsum !',
                    },
                ]
            },
        ],
    ...
}
```

Anyway I hope this helps someone looking for the same thing (I assume Adam Venturella has moved on now)